# Grails 2.3.4 RestController @Caching reponse 404 Not Found returns

Tags: rest, caching, grails, http-status-code-404

Essentially, trying to cache RestController's index method as following.

```
class BookController extends RestfulController<Book> {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    BookRestController() {
        super(Book)
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable("menus")
    def index(Integer max) {
        return super.index(max)
    }
}
```

Testing on command line as following.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:8080/kangurumCms/api/books
```

Result

First time works without cache and swallows response.There is no response on command line.
First response always return 404.

Second time works with cache and returns following result

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Grails-Cached: true
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1644
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 15:34:31 GMT

[{"title":"testestes",....}]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I also had to remove @Cachable annotation in order to get the controllers working. It looks like a bug in the caching plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the annotation is trying to cache all the available formats. I had to create a view to get it work. Try to create an index view.